# Select Item effect in a GridView Builder

Tags: dart, flutter

I have items loaded in GridView.builder from sqflite database. Since the model class of it is not Stateful, ofcourse, I am not able to create Select effect on the items from there.

What i mean by select effect is this:
[image: When users tap on an item, it is selected]

When users tap on an item, it is selected

```
GridView.builder(
                gridDelegate:.....,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
             bool _selectItem = false;
                  return InkWell(
                      onTap: () {},
                      child: Stack(
               children: <Widget>[
               itemsList[index]),        //====Actual Item=====//
             InkWell(onTap: () {         //===To create Select Effect====//
                    setState(() {
                      if (_selectItem == false) {
                        _selectItem = true;
                        print("Item Selected");
                      } else {
                        _selectItem = false;
                        print("Item UnSelected");
                      }
                    });
                  },
                  child: Opacity(
                    opacity: _selectItem == true ? 0.5 : 0.0,
                    child: Icon(Icons.select)                            
                   ),]); },
                itemCount: itemsList.length, 
                 ))
```

I am able to create a select effect, but it selects all items if I tap on any one item. How can create select effect for each individual item.

So how can I create select effect for each individual item?

P.S. I have written only relevant things in the code

**Link to the original question**: [(Flutter) Select Effect on items in Grid View Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55540983/flutter-select-effect-on-items-in-grid-view-builder)

Answer (score -1):

Okay I would suggest you wrap your stateless item into a `GestureDetector`

Then you can decide which gesture you want to detect and react to it, here's the [doc](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html)

Hope it's help

Comment: But how can I call setState in a stateless class

Comment: You can't, this is basically the purpose of setting `Stateless Widget` in the first place, you can wrap the `GestureDetector` in a `Stateful Widget` or you have to refractor you `class`

Comment: Model Class cant be wrapped in Stateful widget as far as i know. I have to setState from GridView builder. But i dont know how. Do you have any idea?

Comment: If you created a `Stateless` widget you can totally refractor it as a `Stateful` one

Comment: I think you didnt get my question properly. I have posted all details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55540983/flutter-select-effect-on-items-in-grid-view-builder

Please check this out. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

You can try using the `Hero` widget for a simple animation, but if you're using custom animations you're going to have to change it to a stateful widget.

short video on hero widget: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Be9UH1kXFDw

Comment: I think you didnt get my question properly. I have posted all details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55540983/flutter-select-effect-on-items-in-grid-view-builder

Please check this out. Thanks :)