# (Flutter) Select Effect on items in Grid View Builder

Tags: dart, flutter

I have items loaded in GridView.builder from sqflite database. Since the model class of it is not Stateful, ofcourse, I am not able to create Select effect on the items from there.

What i mean by select effect is this:
[image: When users tap on an item, it is selected]

When users tap on an item, it is selected

```
GridView.builder(
                gridDelegate:.....,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
             bool _selectItem = false;
                  return Stack(
               children: <Widget>[
               itemsList[index]),        //====Actual Item=====//
             InkWell(onTap: () {         //===To create Select Effect====//
                    setState(() {
                      if (_selectItem == false) {
                        _selectItem = true;
                        print("Item Selected");
                      } else {
                        _selectItem = false;
                        print("Item UnSelected");
                      }
                    });
                  },
                  child: Opacity(
                    opacity: _selectItem == true ? 0.5 : 0.0,
                    child: Icon(Icons.select)                            
                   ),]); },
                itemCount: itemsList.length, 
                 ))
```

I am able to create a select effect, but it selects all items if I tap on any one item. How can create select effect for each individual item.

So how can I create select effect for each individual item?

P.S. I have written only relevant things in the code

Answer (score 3):

Because  of itemList `index` is not managed for selection and unselection,
Your items data loaded in GridView.builder from sqflite database, 
you are manage selection manualy through the local variable into GridView,

Instead of local variable you need to insert selection field into item table,
when inset item into table first time default value item is false.

```
 InkWell(onTap: () {         //===To create Select Effect====//
                setState(() {
                  itemList[index].selectItem  = !itemList[index].selectItem 
                });
              },
```

Then after onTap manage the item selection